# What is the main difference in making between Chocolate Souffle and Chocolate Lava Cake?

Tags: cake, chocolate, souffle

Are chocolate lave cakes a specific type of chocolate souffles or are they a different type of pastry?
Also what is the main difference when making which makes their center a hot liquid sauce instead of gooey?

I used [this recipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3OgS1BtcZvk&t=406s) and liked the result but I want it to have a liquid core like in a molten lava cake, is there a change I can make, or should I try completely different recipe?

Thanks!

Comment: I just googled lava cake recipe and none of the first 3 results I got called for whipping egg whites or even separating the whites (although they do call for extra yolks). I think it's safe to say they're not a kind of souffle.

Comment: I actually made a moltan lava cake yesterday with this recipe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s59tN2J34L8,  and it did call for whipping eggs. The reason I'm asking is that I always remember souffles at restaurents having a liquid chocolate core, and I want to understand if they're just using the wrong name

Comment: I didn't watch the video but I read the text recipe. Whipping whole eggs with sugar will not incorporate nearly as much air as whipping the whites alone, so I wouldn't expect a souffle consistency from this recipe.

Comment: You can fully cook a souffle and still have a fluffy, lofted result. If you fully cook a lava cake, I expect you get something much denser, like a brownie.